# Comparing two different Lists based on Ids

Tags: list, dart, comparison

what I am trying to do here is I am trying to find articles by given id from the CustomerFavoriteRepository. I have two different lists (articleList,FavList ) and I am comparing the ids of both lists and adding them to the empty array (FavartList). Does anyone help me with how can I achieve that using for loop?
I am getting errors at the point of "FavartList.add()" in the loop i don't know which value I have to give there. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is that you need to construct the `NewCustomerFav`, and pass it to the `add` method:

```dart
//this is what i tried 
for (final article in articleList) {
  for (final customArticle in customerFavList) {
    if (article.id == customArticle.articleId) {
      // The values are just for example - I'm not certain how
      // you mean to derive `id` or `like` for a NewCustomerFav.
      final fav = NewCustomerFav(0, article, 1);
      customFavartList.add(fav);
    }
  }
}
```

---

On a different note, your algorithm can be improved here - Right now it will take on the order of n * m operations to build `customFavartList`, where n is the number of articles, and m is the number of favorites.

It can be reduced so that the algorithm performs on the order of n + m, instead, which will scale much better when there are many articles, and the customer has many favorites.

The way to do it is to create a `Set` of ids from the favoritesList, something like this:

```dart
// Assuming customerFavList is a list of int ids
final customerFavIdSet = Set.from(customerFavList.map((e) => e.articleId));

for (final article in articleList) {
  // Now you can check whether the article is a favorite with this one
  // query, rather than searching the whole list.
  if (customerFavIdSet.contains(article.id) {
    final fav = NewCustomerFav(0, article, 1);
    customFavartList.add(fav);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Michael for your answer and your suggestion!. after running your code i am getting output as an instance 
[Instance of 'NewCustomerFav', Instance of 'NewCustomerFav', Instance of 'NewCustomerFav']
but i think it should be the name of articles based on customerfav article ids.
Also is it compulsory to add an instance of NewCustomerFav inside the for loop? or is there any other alternative for that approach?

Comment: If all you need is a list of names, and you don't actually need a list of `NewCustomerFav`, then yes it can be done without constructing the object. You would just change the type of `customFavartList` to `List<String>`, then change `customFavartList.add(fav)` to `customFavArtList.add(article.name)`

Comment: Thanks, @Michael I was looking for something like that it helps a lot! your first comment was super helpful. also, can I ask that is it possible to use a map function instead of two for the loop in the code you have suggested to me?

Comment: Sure thing, you can do that too - You'll need to filter for the articles you want first, then map the results. Here's how that would look on dartpad: https://dartpad.dev/?id=f692bd979603c9726d3aa201ffc8eea4

Comment: Thanks a lot @MichaelHorn. here is what i was exactly looking for. Your suggestions helped to achieve that. Now how can i remove for loop and use only **the map and where method** here?  
`for (final article in articleList) {`
  `for (final customArticle in customerFavList) {
     if (article.id == customArticle.articleId) { `
     ` final fav = NewCustomerFav(customArticle.id, article,customArticle.like ); `
       `customFavartList.add(fav); `
   `  } `
 `  } `
 `} `
   `for( final customFavitem in customFavartList ){ `
    ` print (customFavitem.article.name); `
 `  }`

Comment: The code on dartpad already shows how to do it without the for loop at all :)